# OData v4 WebAPI - Get entity from ODataController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odatacontroller

In my OdataController I am exposing entity Customer (as an example).
I have a method:

```
Get()
```

This works just fine.
To return a single entity I have this method:

```
GetCustomer(int key)
```

This also works just fine.

*** So here's my Question***

Is GetCustomer the only signature option to return a single entity?
I'm not sure how ODataController knows how to resolve this method signature, but Im wondering if there is a generic way to define this.

Answer (score 1):

GetCustomer by default would get a Customer.Customer navigation property. Now you will save a question on stackoverflow ;)
Top get a single entity you can just use Get(int/string key) as follows:

Assume db is your db context instance

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Customer> Get()
{
    return db.Customers;
}

[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Customer> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    IQueryable<Customer> result = db.Customers.Where(p => p.Id == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

Hope it helps.